# What is the best way to find RootViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone please explain me the exact difference between following code lines and preferred one?

```
UIViewController *viewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] rootViewController];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] rootViewController];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] rootViewController];
id viewController4 = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];
```

as I have to show `UIAlertController` from `NSObject` class.

Comment: none are the correct solution, either use delegates, blocks and at worst NotificationCenter to produce the alert from a Controller

Comment: I am smelling a [`XY`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here. If you want to show an alert via non-UI component, then there is clearly something wrong with your design. You should stick to [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) pattern as much as possible for your own good.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am working on a library which does not contains any ViewController class. When someone(customer) invoke methods from my library and between if something went wrong then I have to show some alert instead of giving error message back to customer. For that I want to get ViewController(root) from customer app to show alert. Please advice me If I'm wrong.

Comment: @SeanLintern88, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

From view controller instance, you can use `self.navigationController` to get current navigation controller. Next, you can get `viewControllers` property of current navigation controller, this array present current navigation stack, where first object - root view controller.